# java missing permission when downloading file, even though it has enough

Tags: java, file

```
URL url = null;
URLConnection con;
DataInputStream dis;
        FileOutputStream fos;
        byte[] fileData;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://esdeath.de/downloads/EsdeathClient.rar"); //just example
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert url != null;
        con = url.openConnection();
        dis = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        fileData = new byte[con.getContentLength()];
        for (int q = 0; q < fileData.length; q++) {
            fileData[q] = dis.readByte();
        }
        dis.close(); 
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\max\\desktop")); 
        fos.write(fileData);  
        fos.close();
```

found this in a stackoverflow thread and added the permissions on my manifest as:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
```

for a reason it still says permission denied.

Comment: did you try changing your save location? Perhaps some other drive instead of `C:`.

Comment: i need the data to be downloaded in C: tho.

Comment: first try saving it in a different drive, if it works then its a windows security issue, then run your jar file as admnistrator.

Comment: How do you run a jar file as an admin? cant find option on right click